# linuxkit getty getting stuck

Tags: docker, qemu

I am currently trying out linuxkit external disk. 
However, getty is getting stuck whenever I placed binds definition, it would not go pass the login prompt.

```
kernel:
  image: linuxkit/kernel:4.9.52
  cmdline: "console=tty0 console=ttyS0 console=ttyAMA0"
init:
  - linuxkit/init:7804129bd06218b72c298139a25698a748d253c6
  - linuxkit/runc:a1b564248a0d0b118c11e61db9f84ecf41dd2d2a
  - linuxkit/containerd:417f83f7b8dc1fa36acf90effe44f99c7397480a
  - linuxkit/ca-certificates:e44b0a66df5a102c0e220f0066b0d904710dcb10
onboot:
  - name: sysctl
    image: linuxkit/sysctl:154913b72c6f1f33eb408609fca9963628e8c051
  - name: dhcpcd
    image: linuxkit/dhcpcd:d4408777ed6b6e6e562a5d4938fd09804324b33e
    command: ["/sbin/dhcpcd", "--nobackground", "-f", "/dhcpcd.conf", "-1"]
  - name: format
    image: linuxkit/format:158d992b7bf7ab984100c697d7e72161ea7d7382
  - name: mount
    image: linuxkit/mount:96ac4d32d340ac6e4ddfbf506fa3a497d23649da
    command: ["/usr/bin/mountie", "/tmp"]
services:
  - name: getty
    image: linuxkit/getty:bf6872ce0a9f3ab519b3e502cc41ba3958bda2a6
    capabilities:
     - all
    binds:
     - /tmp:/tmp
  - name: rngd
    image: linuxkit/rngd:558e86a36242bb74353bc9287b715ddb8567357e
files:
  - path: etc/getty.shadow
    # sample sets password for root to "abcdefgh" (without quotes)
    contents: 'root:$6$6tPd2uhHrecCEKug$8mKfcgfwguP7f.BLdZsT1Wz7WIIJOBY1oUFHzIv9/O71M2J0EPdtFqFGTxB1UK5ejqQxRFQ.ZSG9YXR0SNsc11:17322:0:::::'
```

And my linuxkit run command is as follows:

```
linuxkit -v run qemu -disk /home/tweakmy/slowdisk/linuxkit/getty/blank.img,size=3G,format=qcow2 getty2.iso
```

This is the screen where I am stuck:

```
>     [    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.52-linuxkit (root@b81a1f7ba2ff) (gcc version 6.3.0 (Alpine 6.3.0) ) #1 SMP Thu Sep 28 15:02:54 UTC
> 2017
>     [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/kernel console=tty0 console=ttyS0 console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sr0
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
>     [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'eager' FPU context switches.
>     [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003ffdefff] usable
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000003ffdf000-0x000000003fffffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000b0000000-0x00000000bfffffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
>     [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
>     [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.8 present.
>     [    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x3ffdf max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
>     [    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WC  UC- WT  
>     [    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f6630-0x000f663f] mapped at [ffff92a1000f6630]
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F6460 000014 (v00 BOCHS )
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: RSDT 0x000000003FFE2267 000038 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCRSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x000000003FFE1E32 000074 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCFACP 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x000000003FFE0040 001DF2 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCDSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x000000003FFE0000 000040
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000003FFE1EA6 0002D5 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCSSDT 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x000000003FFE217B 000078 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCAPIC 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x000000003FFE21F3 000038 (v01 BOCHS  BXPCHPET 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x000000003FFE222B 00003C (v01 BOCHS  BXPCMCFG 00000001 BXPC 00000001)
>     [    0.000000] Zone ranges:
>     [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
>     [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x000000003ffdefff]
>     [    0.000000]   Normal   empty
>     [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
>     [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
>     [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
>     [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000003ffdefff]
>     [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000003ffdefff]
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x608
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
>     [    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
>     [    0.000000] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
>     [    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a201 base: 0xfed00000
>     [    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 1 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
>     [    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x40000000-0xafffffff] available for PCI devices
>     [    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
>     [    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
>     [    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:128 nr_cpumask_bits:128 nr_cpu_ids:1 nr_node_ids:1
>     [    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 35 pages/cpu @ffff92a13fc00000 s105240 r8192 d29928 u2097152
>     [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 257896
>     [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/kernel console=tty0 console=ttyS0 console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/sr0
>     [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
>     [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
>     [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
>     [    0.000000] Memory: 1014172K/1048052K available (8035K kernel code, 1367K rwdata, 2696K rodata, 1380K init, 568K bss, 33880K
> reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
>     [    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
>     [    0.000000]    Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 64.
>     [    0.000000]    RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=128 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
>     [    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=1
>     [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:8448 nr_irqs:256 16
>     [    0.000000] Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
>     [    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
>     [    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
>     [    0.000000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604467 ns
>     [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
>     [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 3394.161 MHz processor
>     [    0.020805] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 6788.32 BogoMIPS (lpj=33941610)
>     [    0.021301] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
>     [    0.021766] ACPI: Core revision 20160831
>     [    0.051169] ACPI: 2 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
>     [    0.052932] Security Framework initialized
>     [    0.053092] Yama: becoming mindful.
>     [    0.054186] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.054407] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.065666] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
>     [    0.065816] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
>     [    0.213551] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 20K
>     [    0.218208] ftrace: allocating 35516 entries in 139 pages
>     [    0.316894] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
>     [    0.323220] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
>     [    0.430000] smpboot: CPU0: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+ (family: 0x6, model: 0x6, stepping: 0x3)
>     [    0.430000] Performance Events: PMU not available due to virtualization, using software events only.
>     [    0.430000] x86: Booted up 1 node, 1 CPUs
>     [    0.430000] smpboot: Total of 1 processors activated (6788.32 BogoMIPS)
>     [    0.431509] NMI watchdog: disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
>     [    0.431704] NMI watchdog: Shutting down hard lockup detector on all cpus
>     [    0.440776] devtmpfs: initialized
>     [    0.443633] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
>     [    0.478379] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
>     [    0.478698] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.483445] NET: Registered protocol family 16
>     [    0.489199] cpuidle: using governor ladder
>     [    0.489359] cpuidle: using governor menu
>     [    0.490130] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
>     [    0.491828] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xb0000000-0xbfffffff] (base 0xb0000000)
>     [    0.492159] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xb0000000-0xbfffffff] reserved in E820
>     [    0.492812] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
>     [    0.531450] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
>     [    0.538790] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
>     [    0.538902] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
>     [    0.539012] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
>     [    0.539147] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
>     [    0.585379] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
>     [    0.585758] ACPI: (supports S0 S5)
>     [    0.586102] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
>     [    0.587008] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
>     [    0.619328] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
>     [    0.619839] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
>     [    0.623139] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME PCIeCapability]
>     [    0.625196] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
>     [    0.625377] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
>     [    0.625564] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
>     [    0.625743] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
>     [    0.625948] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xc0000000-0xfebfffff window]
>     [    0.626226] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
>     [    0.651380] pci 0000:00:1f.0: quirk: [io  0x0600-0x067f] claimed by ICH6 ACPI/GPIO/TCO
>     [    0.671821] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
>     [    0.673270] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
>     [    0.674330] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
>     [    0.675368] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
>     [    0.676522] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
>     [    0.677613] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
>     [    0.678626] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
>     [    0.679460] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
>     [    0.679860] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIA] (IRQs *16)
>     [    0.680257] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIB] (IRQs *17)
>     [    0.680507] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIC] (IRQs *18)
>     [    0.680763] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSID] (IRQs *19)
>     [    0.681018] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIE] (IRQs *20)
>     [    0.681270] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIF] (IRQs *21)
>     [    0.681531] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIG] (IRQs *22)
>     [    0.681773] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIH] (IRQs *23)
>     [    0.684151] ACPI: Enabled 16 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
>     [    0.687071] SCSI subsystem initialized
>     [    0.688025] ACPI: bus type USB registered
>     [    0.688723] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
>     [    0.689160] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
>     [    0.690058] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
>     [    0.690710] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
>     [    0.690836] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
>     [    0.691124] PTP clock support registered
>     [    0.691748] wmi: Mapper loaded
>     [    0.692310] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
>     [    0.702615] NetLabel: Initializing
>     [    0.702735] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
>     [    0.702860] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
>     [    0.703897] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
>     [    0.704460] HPET: 3 timers in total, 0 timers will be used for per-cpu timer
>     [    0.705076] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0
>     [    0.705363] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 100.000000 MHz counter
>     [    0.710792] clocksource: Switched to clocksource hpet
>     [    0.853794] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
>     [    0.854214] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
>     [    0.855696] FS-Cache: Loaded
>     [    0.858617] CacheFiles: Loaded
>     [    0.859503] pnp: PnP ACPI init
>     [    0.870398] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 5 devices
>     [    0.902634] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
>     [    0.904149] NET: Registered protocol family 2
>     [    0.908186] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
>     [    0.908544] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
>     [    0.908888] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
>     [    0.910261] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.910503] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
>     [    0.911805] NET: Registered protocol family 1
>     [    0.912306] pci 0000:00:01.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
>     [    0.929224] PCLMULQDQ-NI instructions are not detected.
>     [    0.929727] AVX or AES-NI instructions are not detected.
>     [    0.929918] CPU feature 'AVX registers' is not supported.
>     [    0.930322] CPU feature 'AVX registers' is not supported.
>     [    0.930516] CPU feature 'AVX registers' is not supported.
>     [    0.930679] CPU feature 'AVX registers' is not supported.
>     [    0.930853] AVX2 or AES-NI instructions are not detected.
>     [    0.931025] AVX2 instructions are not detected.
>     [    0.934248] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
>     [    0.935302] audit: type=2000 audit(1507033386.930:1): initialized
>     [    0.939467] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
>     [    0.943051] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
>     [    0.943453] fuse init (API version 7.26)
>     [    0.944703] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, no debug enabled
>     [    0.946675] 9p: Installing v9fs 9p2000 file system support
>     [    0.946881] FS-Cache: Netfs '9p' registered for caching
>     [    0.963743] NET: Registered protocol family 38
>     [    0.964009] Key type asymmetric registered
>     [    0.964162] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
>     [    0.964553] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
>     [    0.965177] io scheduler noop registered
>     [    0.965335] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
>     [    0.965680] io scheduler cfq registered
>     [    0.967207] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
>     [    0.967409] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
>     [    0.967786] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
>     [    0.968171] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_fb
>     [    0.970941] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
>     [    0.971483] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
>     [    0.974145] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
>     [    0.979701] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIG] enabled at IRQ 22
>     [    0.981277] virtio-pci 0000:00:02.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
>     [    0.986222] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIH] enabled at IRQ 23
>     [    0.986554] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
>     [    0.987788] xenfs: not registering filesystem on non-xen platform
>     [    0.989043] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
>     [    1.011940] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
>     [    1.018118] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
>     [    1.021651] Hangcheck: starting hangcheck timer 0.9.1 (tick is 180 seconds, margin is 60 seconds).
>     [    1.051511] loop: module loaded
>     [    1.058762] nbd: registered device at major 43
>     [    1.085048] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: RCBA is disabled by hardware/BIOS, device disabled
>     [    1.085414] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: I/O space for GPIO uninitialized
>     [    1.085629] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: No MFD cells added
>     [    1.086574] VMware PVSCSI driver - version 1.0.7.0-k
>     [    1.086921] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_storvsc
>     [    1.092274] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [GSIA] enabled at IRQ 16
>     [    1.095960] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0000 32 slots 6 ports 1.5 Gbps 0x3f impl SATA mode
>     [    1.096204] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: ncq only 
>     [    1.111650] scsi host0: ahci
>     [    1.113866] scsi host1: ahci
>     [    1.115211] scsi host2: ahci
>     [    1.116497] scsi host3: ahci
>     [    1.117772] scsi host4: ahci
>     [    1.119029] scsi host5: ahci
>     [    1.120130] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfebd2000 port 0xfebd2100 irq 24
>     [    1.120448] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfebd2000 port 0xfebd2180 irq 24
>     [    1.120645] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfebd2000 port 0xfebd2200 irq 24
>     [    1.120847] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfebd2000 port 0xfebd2280 irq 24
>     [    1.121067] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfebd2000 port 0xfebd2300 irq 24
>     [    1.121290] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m4096@0xfebd2000 port 0xfebd2380 irq 24
>     [    1.127988] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
>     [    1.128131] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
>     [    1.135619] VMware vmxnet3 virtual NIC driver - version 1.4.a.0-k-NAPI
>     [    1.136192] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_netvsc
>     [    1.136435] Fusion MPT base driver 3.04.20
>     [    1.136628] Copyright (c) 1999-2008 LSI Corporation
>     [    1.136939] Fusion MPT SPI Host driver 3.04.20
>     [    1.138154] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
>     [    1.141004] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
>     [    1.141291] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
>     [    1.143263] hv_vmbus: registering driver hyperv_keyboard
>     [    1.144518] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
>     [    1.146480] random: fast init done
>     [    1.147649] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input1
>     [    1.149387] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input2
>     [    1.152614] rtc_cmos 00:00: RTC can wake from S4
>     [    1.156152] rtc_cmos 00:00: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
>     [    1.157273] rtc_cmos 00:00: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
>     [    1.157913] i2c /dev entries driver
>     [    1.159306] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.35.0-ioctl (2016-06-23) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
>     [    1.163046] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
>     [    1.163345] usbhid: USB HID core driver
>     [    1.163761] hv_utils: Registering HyperV Utility Driver
>     [    1.163992] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_util
>     [    1.164204] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_balloon
>     [    1.164536] oprofile: using NMI interrupt.
>     [    1.165219] GACT probability on
>     [    1.165513] Mirror/redirect action on
>     [    1.166086] Simple TC action Loaded
>     [    1.166446] u32 classifier
>     [    1.166583]     Performance counters on
>     [    1.166761]     input device check on
>     [    1.166934]     Actions configured
>     [    1.167295] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
>     [    1.167631] nfnl_acct: registering with nfnetlink.
>     [    1.168502] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (8192 buckets, 32768 max)
>     [    1.170713] ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
>     [    1.173036] nf_tables: (c) 2007-2009 Patrick McHardy <kaber@trash.net>
>     [    1.173555] nf_tables_compat: (c) 2012 Pablo Neira Ayuso <pablo@netfilter.org>
>     [    1.174999] xt_time: kernel timezone is -0000
>     [    1.175250] ip_set: protocol 6
>     [    1.175601] IPVS: Registered protocols (TCP, UDP, SCTP, AH, ESP)
>     [    1.175912] IPVS: Connection hash table configured (size=4096, memory=64Kbytes)
>     [    1.176885] IPVS: Creating netns size=2104 id=0
>     [    1.178270] IPVS: ipvs loaded.
>     [    1.178429] IPVS: [rr] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.178613] IPVS: [wrr] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.178781] IPVS: [lc] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.178943] IPVS: [wlc] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.179104] IPVS: [fo] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.179258] IPVS: [ovf] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.179479] IPVS: [lblc] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.179701] IPVS: [lblcr] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.179882] IPVS: [dh] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.180044] IPVS: [sh] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.180598] IPVS: [sed] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.180857] IPVS: [nq] scheduler registered.
>     [    1.181507] IPVS: ftp: loaded support on port[0] = 21
>     [    1.182279] ipip: IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
>     [    1.186673] gre: GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor driver
>     [    1.188779] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
>     [    1.191375] ipt_CLUSTERIP: ClusterIP Version 0.8 loaded successfully
>     [    1.191803] arp_tables: arp_tables: (C) 2002 David S. Miller
>     [    1.193550] NET: Registered protocol family 10
>     [    1.199911] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
>     [    1.204865] NET: Registered protocol family 17
>     [    1.205437] Bridge firewalling registered
>     [    1.205702] Ebtables v2.0 registered
>     [    1.206749] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
>     [    1.207607] 9pnet: Installing 9P2000 support
>     [    1.208453] Key type dns_resolver registered
>     [    1.209055] microcode: AMD CPU family 0x6 not supported
>     [    1.211556] registered taskstats version 1
>     [    1.221238] Key type big_key registered
>     [    1.222689] Key type encrypted registered
>     [    1.224875] rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2017-10-03 12:23:07 UTC (1507033387)
>     [    1.452864] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
>     [    1.456756] ata3.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
>     [    1.457129] ata3.00: applying bridge limits
>     [    1.458326] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
>     [    1.459404] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
>     [    1.460621] ata1.00: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
>     [    1.460936] ata1.00: 6291456 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
>     [    1.461326] ata1.00: applying bridge limits
>     [    1.462129] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
>     [    1.463843] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
>     [    1.464096] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
>     [    1.464642] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
>     [    1.465121] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
>     [    1.476104] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
>     [    1.481672] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 6291456 512-byte logical blocks: (3.22 GB/3.00 GiB)
>     [    1.483328] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
>     [    1.483818] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
>     [    1.486493] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
>     [    1.490757] scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
>     [    1.492993] sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
>     [    1.493262] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
>     [    1.501226] sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
>     [    1.502777]  sda: sda1
>     [    1.509588] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
>     [    1.545030] FAT-fs (sr0): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
>     [    1.547194] FAT-fs (sr0): utf8 is not a recommended IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
>     [    1.551881] VFS: Mounted root (iso9660 filesystem) readonly on device 11:0.
>     [    1.632754] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1380K
>     [    1.632905] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
>     [    1.636369] Freeing unused kernel memory: 140K
>     [    1.703301] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1400K
>     [    1.920501] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3394.155 MHz
>     [    1.920948] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x30ecbcc6c3d, max_idle_ns: 440795207542 ns
>     [    2.940581] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
>     
>     Welcome to LinuxKit
>     
>                             ##         .
>                       ## ## ##        ==
>                    ## ## ## ## ##    ===
>                /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
>               {                       /  ===-
>                \______ O           __/
>                  \    \         __/
>                   \____\_______/
>     
>     [    6.609377] 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
>     [    7.123456] IPVS: Creating netns size=2104 id=1
>     [    7.123918] IPVS: ftp: loaded support on port[0] = 21
>     [    8.354013] IPVS: Creating netns size=2104 id=2
>     [    8.354294] IPVS: ftp: loaded support on port[0] = 21
>     [    9.536923] random: crng init done
>     [    9.604634] EXT4-fs (sda1): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
>     [    9.609077] EXT4-fs (sda1): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities
>     [    9.661331] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>     [   14.967631] IPVS: Creating netns size=2104 id=3
>     [   14.968941] IPVS: ftp: loaded support on port[0] = 21
```

I can see the mounting. But I am not too sure the mounting did eventually happend on the linuxkit guest?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a little bit unclear on this: `binds` doesn't **add** the mount points, but **replaces** them. The documentation update is pending, but to solve your particular problem, just please put all the existing binds into the `.yml` (an example below shows how to add the custom aliases to `getty`):

```
services:
  - name: getty
    image: linuxkit/getty:bf6872ce0a9f3ab519b3e502cc41ba3958bda2a6
    env:
      - INSECURE=true
    binds:
      - /etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
      - /run:/run
      - /tmp:/tmp
      - /etc:/hostroot/etc
      - /usr/bin/ctr:/usr/bin/ctr
      - /usr/bin/runc:/usr/bin/runc
      - /containers:/containers
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - /dev:/dev
      - /sys:/sys
      - /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh:/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh
files:
  - path: etc/profile.d/aliases.sh
    contents: |
      alias c='clear'
```

Comment: Thanks. The info was helpful